# Disable popup messages when selecting with the marker?

Tags: xcode, popup, settings

Every other time I select some code with my marker for copy/paste reasons, a popup message is shown which prevents me from copying the selected code. It seems completely random when it appears and what type of popup appear - sometimes it shows, other times it doesn't. Sometimes it says something about quick help and other times it's a summary description of framework code. Can I disable these messages somehow? I can't show an image here because my reputation is too low.

Answer (score -1):

I had been struggling with this for quite some time and for me it was not consistent enough to figure out the true cause. Finally, I dug deeper and found that the issue relates to the amount of finger pressure applied to the TrackPad when making a text selection.  The popups in Xcode are triggered by the gesture for "Look up & data detectors".  I'm now using macOS Ventura which has a Setting to change the gesture from "Force Click with One Finger" to "Tap with Three Fingers".

In your System Settings for TrackPad change this:
[image]

to this:
[image]