# How to disable Quick Help in Xcode 11.5

Tags: xcode

I installed Xcode 11.5 and "Quick Help" keep popping up whenever I made a selection. This is really irritating as I need to dismiss it before I can continue. All the answers that I can find online are about re-enabling it, but how to disable it? I prefer to use it only when needed, not automatically pop-up every time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, the issue was not entirely in Xcode. I installed Catalina OS followed by Xcode 11.5 and the symptom above appeared. After switching on/off some settings in System Preference, the "Quick Help on text selection" issue was resolved.

I disabled "Force Click and haptic feedback" under Trackpad. Guess it was the "press firmly" when selecting the text that triggered the Quick Help.

[image]

Comment: Here is similar question and a solution for macOS Ventura:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75891083/899918